# Big O notation complexity in three cases

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Do following algorithms run in O(n) time?

**1**

```
s=0
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        s=s+i*j;
    }

    s=s+1
}
```

This is a O(n^2) since here performance directly proportional to the square of the size of the input data set N

**2**

```
 s=0
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    { if (i>20)
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            s=s+i*j;
        }

        s=s+1
    }
```

**3**

```
 s=0
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    { if(i<4)
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            s=s+i*j;
        }

        s=s+1
    }
```

Can you please explain how the if statement affects O(n)? In both cases (#2 and #3) first loop is O(n) and the second loop is going to run if N > 20 or N < 4 respectively. But how this affects complexity? Will these are still be O(n^2) with `if i > 20` does 20^2 operations less and `if i < 4` 4^2 less? Also that Big O assumes that N is going to infinity?

Comment: What do you yourself think of #2 and #3?

Comment: @Gassa I've edited my question

Comment: How many times will the body of the inner loop be run in each case?

Comment: @interjay 20^2 operations less in first case and 4^2 less in the second?

Comment: second case complexity is the same with first one. third case is linear because the inner loop always runs 4 times

Comment: No, try to count how many times the inner loop runs, how many operations it performs each time, and multiply.

Comment: From your last sentence, it seems like you don't know what the definition of big-O is. A good starting point to any mathematical question  is to know exactly what each term you use means (and what each term in the definition of those terms mean and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2**

Still `O(N^2)`. The loop runs a total of

20 + (N - 20) * N iterations (and each iteration is constant) ==> O (N^2)

**3**

`O(N)`. The loop runs a total of

N * 4 + (N - 4) iterations (and each iteration is constant) ==> O(N)

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense now.